# How can I replace the top row of function key with media keys? (thinkpad)

Tags: unity, 14.04, shortcut-keys, thinkpad, x230

The thinkpad x230 has a top row of function keys which can be used as media keys by pressing 
 <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>FX</kbd>

I would like to **not** have to press the <kbd>fn</kbd> keys, i.e. only pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> would start playing music. I believe this used to be the behavior of ubuntu on my old Macbook, but on my thinkpad this is not the case.

How can I enable this?

Note:
Unlike the thinkpad edge series, there is no option in the BIOS menu to enable the desired functionality.

[image]